# Magento: Multiple custom contact forms

Tags: forms, zend-framework, magento

I want to build a custom contact form based around the existing contact form. Is it necessary to build a custom module for new contact forms or is it possible extend the built-in somehow?

Obviously if I try to duplicate and rename the current contact form I would be re-using that controller which won't process the correct data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did exactly this by creating my own custom module.

Mine was different enough to warrant it being a custom module as I needed to be able to change it's configuration via the admin, as well as a number of other changes. I didn't see how I could just extend the existing form/code as I was basically changing every aspect of it.

My advice would be to have a look at how the existing form works and pull out what you need into your own module.

I basically ended up with a frontend form and a controller, with various pieces of plumbing to allow me to configure things from the admin side.

Comment: Yup, this is exactly what I determined I needed to do too so it is now underway :) Thanks for the incite.